# C++: tusing boost unordered_map error:no matching function call

Tags: c++, boost, initialization, unordered-map

I have the following code:

struct STFRandomTreeFunction
    {
        typedef double (*function_ptr)(const STFDataPoint& data, boost::unordered_map& preloaded_images);
    };

```
struct STFRandomTreeFunctor
{
private:
    boost::unordered_map<std::string, cv::Mat> *image_cache;
    STFRandomTreeFunction::function_ptr function;
    std::string function_id;

public:
    STFRandomTreeFunctor(boost::unordered_map<std::string, cv::Mat>& cache, STFRandomTreeFunction::function_ptr function, std::string function_id)
    :image_cache(&cache), function(function), function_id(function_id){}

    std::string get_function_id(){
        return function_id;
    }

    double operator()(const TrainingDataPoint& data_point){
        return function(data_point, *image_cache);
    }
};

unordered_map<string, STFRandomTreeFunctor> lut;

double a(const STFDataPoint& b, unordered_map<string, Mat>& c){
    return 5;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    unordered_map<string, Mat> cache;
    lut["a"] = STFRandomTreeFunctor(cache, a, "a");
}
```

when I try to build I get the following error: `boost/unordered/detail/allocate.hpp:262:1: error: no matching function for call to ‘STFRandomTreeFunctor::STFRandomTreeFunctor()’`

But I have no idea why boost is trying to call `STFRandomTreeFunctor()`, is this because when we create the empty map, it tries to create a STFRandomTreeFunctor? If so, how can I work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call

```
lut["a"] = x;
```

will first create an empty entry in `themap` (cfr. [operator[]](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#id3723627-bb): "Effects:
If the container does not already contain an elements with a key equivalent to k, inserts the value `std::pair<key_type const, mapped_type>(k, mapped_type())`").  To construct `mapped_type()` it needs a default constructor.

If you want to avoid that, use the [`insert`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#id3724474-bb) function:

```
bool inserted=lut.insert( std::make_pair("a",x) ).second;
assert(inserted); // unless it's ok to not overwrite already inserted keys
```

But this way, you'll need a copy constructor (or a [move-constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx)), since the newly created `pair` will be copied into the map.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `lut["a"]` in your main function, map should return a reference to an initialized value of type `STFRandomTreeFunctor` and as you see, it have no parameter to create and initialize that instance, so it use default constructor of your class and your class have no default constructor. so you should either, write a default constructor for your class or use:

```
lut.insert( std::make_pair("a", STFRandomTreeFunctor(cache, a, "a")) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your struct definitions on top, basically it's trying to construct the `unordered_map<string, STFRandomTreeFunctor> lut;` but can't find the definition for your struct :)

```
struct STFRandomTreeFunction
{
    typedef double (*function_ptr)(const STFDataPoint& data, boost::unordered_map<std::string, cv::Mat>& preloaded_images);
};

struct STFRandomTreeFunctor
{
private:
    boost::unordered_map<std::string, cv::Mat> *image_cache;
    STFRandomTreeFunction::function_ptr function;
    std::string function_id;

public:
    STFRandomTreeFunctor(boost::unordered_map<std::string, cv::Mat>& cache, STFRandomTreeFunction::function_ptr function, std::string function_id)
    :image_cache(&cache), function(function), function_id(function_id){}

    std::string get_function_id(){
        return function_id;
    }

    double operator()(const TrainingDataPoint& data_point){
        return function(data_point, *image_cache);
    }
};

unordered_map<string, STFRandomTreeFunctor> lut;

double a(const STFDataPoint& b, unordered_map<string, Mat>& c){
    return 5;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    unordered_map<string, Mat> cache;
    lut["a"] = STFRandomTreeFunctor(cache, a, "a");
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I just copied them in wrong, the structs are actually defined in a header file which is included, I will edit the post to reflect this